# JQuery Mobile Super Slow Performance On iPhone 3GS

Tags: javascript, iphone, performance, mobile, jquery-mobile

Hi I have a page with a header, a content pane, and about 120 list items. Basically this performs so sloow and buggily on an iphone 3gs with ios5.

Here are some of what it does :

1. There is a login page before that page above, to get to that page above the spinner spins then STOPS spinning and freezes, then the screen goes all grey for about a second or 2, then the page above displays (and Im hosting the website locally on a server).
2. Once the page loads, it hesitates a lot to scroll down, every scroll stops then starts, its very jerky until Ive scrolled all the way down once then its a bit better. While scrolling down the page goes completely blank often with checkerboard background...
3. Upon a tap of any item on the above list it takes approx 3 seconds to light up blue, then takes another couple of seconds to actually go to the next page (same freezing issue with spinner).
4. Once the next page loads its content is mashed up with the page above, so they are like on top of each other, it takes a second for that to disappear.

As you can see, a terrible experience. My company has many 3gs phones, any way I can improve the performance?

EDIT 1:

Here is the complete page code : http://pastebin.com/VLXyeCty

The custom.css contains 1 style to fix the bubble position in latest jqm :

```
.ui-li-has-alt .ui-li-count {
    right: 67px !important;
}
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10628842/1124854](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10628842/1124854)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile Filtered List slow with 150 items on iPhone 3GS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991867/jquery-mobile-filtered-list-slow-with-150-items-on-iphone-3gs)