# jQuery iPhone 3gs performance

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have a performance related question; specifically to iPhone 3gs.
I have a jQuery Mobile site that responded well on my friend's iPhone 3gs until a recent change I've made.
Since the change, on the 3gs, the page in question seems to be very slow.....almost unusable.
The page still runs great on a galaxy S2, but after checking the benchmarks for javascript I can see the S2 is able to handle javascript much better so I guess there's no surprise there.
Also the iPhone 4 should not have a problem going off the benchmark figures.

The code I've added is pretty simple.
It just removes the href from 12 buttons on the page and handles click events.
Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mybutton').removeAttr("href");

  $('.mybutton').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("inactive") || $(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("active inactive");
    }

    // Disable if 1 active button, else inactive
    if($('.active').length == 1) {
      $('.inactive').toggleClass("inactive disabled");
    } else {
      $('.disabled').toggleClass("disabled inactive");
    }
  });

});
```

Is there anything I can do to speed up that code for iPhone 3gs?
Should I even be bothered about this phone? Does anyone still use one barring my technologically challenged work colleague? :)

Comment: FYI, it is said the desktop jQuery is faster than mobile on the mobile devices :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10554601/792677